# UI updates with weather data after 2 clicks, but only on the first time then doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I am building a weather app that shows weather data depending on the city, the user selects the city from a drop-down, then the city name is sent to the server with a post request using fetch, and the server makes a get request to the open weather map API using Axios, gets the weather data and sends it back to the frontend using a get request then this data is used to update the UI.

Now when I first click submit, I get 2 error messages in the console **`GET http://localhost:3000/fulldata 404 (Not Found)`** and **`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`** then when I click again, the UI updates correctly, then when I choose another city and click submit again, nothing happens, no new errors in the console or the terminal. I tried to await the  sendCityToServer function but then the UI doesn't update even on the second click and no errors are shown in the console or terminal

**Frontend code**

```js
    // Global Variables
    const SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/'
    const COUNTRIES_NAMES_API = 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all'

    // Create a new date instance dynamically with JS
    let d = new Date().toDateString()

    // HTML Selectors
    const generate = document.querySelector('#generate')
    const date = document.querySelector('.date')
    const temp = document.querySelector('.temperature')
    const weatherCondition = document.querySelector('.weatherCondition')
    const country = document.querySelector('.place')
    const weatherIcon = document.querySelector('.wi')

    const countriesNames = async () => {
      const select = document.querySelector('#countries')

      const countriesList = await (await fetch(COUNTRIES_NAMES_API)).json()

      countriesList.splice(38, 1)

      countriesList.forEach(country => {
        const option = document.createElement('option')
        if (country.capital) {
          option.innerText = `${country.capital[0]}`
          select.append(option)
        }
      })
    }

    // Getting data from API
    const APIdata = async () => {
      const citySelector = document.querySelector('#countries').value
      sendCityToServer(`${SERVER_URL}postcityselector`, { city: citySelector })

      // API Keys
      const data = await (await fetch(`${SERVER_URL}fulldata`)).json()
      // Update UI with API data

      weatherIcon.src = `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${data.weather[0].icon}@4x.png`
      date.innerText = date
      temp.innerText = Math.floor(data.main.temp) + '°C'
      weatherCondition.innerText = data.weather[0].description
      country.innerText = data.name
    }

    // Update UI when button is clicked
    generate.addEventListener('click', APIdata)

    async function sendCityToServer(url = '', data = {}) {
      const response = fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      })
    }

    countriesNames()
```

**Server code** (Removed the setup of express, body parser, cors and dotenv)

```js
    const apiKeys = {
      URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
      KEY: process.env.API_KEY,
    }

    weatherData = {}




    app.post('/postcityselector', req => {
      axios.get(apiKeys.URL + req.body.city + apiKeys.KEY).then(response => {
        app.get('/fulldata', (req, res) => {
          res.send(response.data)
        })
      })
    })
```

Comment: It looks like the server can’t find `http://localhost:3000/fulldata` and so it’s sending an HTML 404 page. The second message is because the code can’t parse that HTML response as JSON, but it’s really a side effect of the first error.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.